# Play video in VirtualBox guest

Tags: video, 12.04, virtualbox, windows-7, 2d

I am installing Windows 7 today with Ubuntu 12.04 Beta 2 as a VirtualBox guest. Can Ubuntu (as a guest) play 2D videos within VirtualBox? Is there anything I need to install or enable?

I remember Windows 7 as a VirtualBox guest can play videos, but I don't remember how good a quality they were.

Hopefully someone out there knows what todo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, VirtualBox will play videos just fine, and quality should be good as long as the guest additions are installed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 2D videos will play fine. I am running Windows 7 SP1 with Ubuntu 12.04beta2 in a virtualBox (4.1.10) VM and HD (1080) videos played reasonably well. (Minor screen tearing). 720 HD videos play better, I noticed. (less screen tearing)

As Jayson Rowe stated, make sure you install the virtualbox 'guest additions'. You can do so from the VM window's 'Devices' menu.